# year and date are jumbled in date from factor

Tags: r

I have a dateframe where the date is in factor. But when i convert it into the `"%d-%m-%Y"` results in for eg: `1998-08-07` the year and date gets jumbled.

I have put a sample code in factor format below because my original data has got in  factor format.

Help me convert the factor to date.

Code I tried:

```
date = c("07-08-1998","15-11-1966")
date = as.factor(date)

as.Date(date, format="%d-%m-%Y")

Result : [1] "1998-08-07" "1966-11-15"
```

Expected:

```
Result : [1] "07-08-1998" "15-11-1966"
```

Comment: The standard format for _displaying_ Date objects is the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD. If you want to _print_ Date objects in a different format, please, use the `format()` function to print. Factor has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: i used format still year and date are jumbled

Comment: The help file on `as.Date()` gives a detailed explanation of functions to convert between character representations and objects of class "Date" representing calendar dates. Please, see `help("as.Date")`.

Comment: Do you need `format(as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")`  but this is exactly same as your original `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may format a date not a factor! Based on what Ronak Shah suggested:

```
date = c("07-08-1998","15-11-1966")
date = as.factor(date)
format(as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
#"07-08-1998" "15-11-1966"
```